# Using `sys` how can I import a file from a filepath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

There was an answer to this in this question ([How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631/4518341)). It is the second answer with like 400 upvotes. However, the answer was never edited to include what many people commented asking for.

In the answer he says to do this:

'The advantage of adding a path to sys.path (over using imp) is that it simplifies things when importing more than one module from a single package. For example:

```
import sys
# the mock-0.3.1 dir contains testcase.py, testutils.py & mock.py
sys.path.append('/foo/bar/mock-0.3.1')

from testcase import TestCase
from testutils import RunTests
from mock import Mock, sentinel, patch
```

'

What many people were asking was basically how do we use `sys.path.append` to point to a single python file instead of a directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `sys.path` doesn't work that way. It's a list of directories to look in, not files to look at.

Comment: Is there another way that I could accomplish this task instead without sys? Given the filepath? The top answer in that question did not work for me

Comment: @newtopython: Ask a separate question about the failure you saw, including enough code and context to reproduce the error.